# git ftp push with lftp on windows

Tags: git, ssl, ftp, lftp, git-ftp

I am pretty fed up with own inability to get this running, sorry.

git and git-ftp are installed ok, git ftp push works fine(albeit only with plain ftp, not sftp). I am trying to get git ftp pull/download to work since there are situations where ftp content is changed directly.

The lftp is needed for that so got LFTP for Windows from Nwgat. It is a standalone, I put it into program files/lftp (bin and etc folders), set env. path, lftp runs now from commandline.

git ftp pull produces following error with first lftp command "cd"

`Fatal error: Certificate verification: unable to get local issuer certificate`

I can use lftp directly with success
`lftp ftp://username@ftp.server.com`
then set commands

> set ssl:verify-certificate no
>
> set ftp:ssl-allow no;

but when git calls lftp something is wrong and a certificate is in play, I assume forced SSL connection. So I added

> set ssl:verify-certificate no
>
> set ftp:ssl-allow no;

to C:\Program Files\lftp\etc\lftp.conf

However calling "set" in lftp does not show any of the config parameters, so I assume lftp from git-ftp does not respect the ssl settings...

Any ideas before I start writing my own shell script instead of git ftp pull? :)

*EDIT: It seems the config file is ignored in lftp, no matter if it is called from git or directly. Where the hell is lftp looking for config file? Tried users/user/.lftprc, failed.*

thanks
Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I found out I had a messed up installation of git-ftp also messed up install of cygwin. When I reinstalled all from scratch, everything works well :)